# For which value of $x \in R $ the following series converges $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{1+x^{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For which value of $x \in R $ the following series converges

$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{1+x^{2n}}$

The series of the absolute values is $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{x^{n}}{1+x^{2n}}|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x|^{n}}{1+x^{2n}}$

and applying the root test:
$ lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{ \frac{|x|^{n}}{1+x^{2n}}}= lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{|x|}{\sqrt[n] {1+x^{2n}}}  = 
|x| lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{\sqrt[n] {1+x^{2n}}} = |x|* \frac{ 1}{x^2}= \frac{ 1}{|x|}$

$\frac{ 1}{|x|}<1$ $ \forall x \in R $ with $|x|>1$

while the solution should be $|x| \ne 1$
and I'm not sure about the limit.

Can someone help me to understant where is the mistake?

Comment: If $|x| < 1$ then $\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}} \to 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation in the root test is wrong when $|x|\lt1$. It should be
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}\right|^{1/n}=|x|
$$
For $|x|\gt1$, your computation is correct:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}\right|^{1/n}=\frac1{|x|}
$$
Now you just need to consider the case $|x|=1$.

Comment: if $x=n$ the limit becomes $1$ and the series doesn't converge

Comment: @Anne How could be $x=n$?

Comment: @Anne: if $x=\color{#C00}{1}$, then the root test is inconclusive. The limit being $1$ does not tell you that the series diverges. You might then try the term test; i.e. do the terms vanish as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @robjohn yes, I made a mistake writing , if $x=1$ the series diverges, if $x=-1$ the series has no limit because the sequence of the absolute values is not monotonically decreasing and the limit is not $0$ (leibniz test)